# Keep bootstrap slider horizantal below 991px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a Bootstrap slider with a CSS grid. A demo can be [seen here][1].

When I resize my screen to `< 991px` the slider is turning vertical, and going out of the CSS grid in the class `item5`. I would like the slider is turning into 1 row like this:

[image]

But to be honest I do not know where to start if it is possible at all. Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Best regards.

```css
      .wrapper {
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns:repeat(12,1fr);
        grid-gap: 10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 10px solid #fff;
      } 

      .wrapper > div {
        background-color: #eee;
        padding: 1em;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #ddd;
      }
      
      .item5 {
          grid-row: 3 / 6;
          grid-column: 1 / 13;
          height: 290px;
        }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .wrapper {
          display:grid;
          grid-template-columns:repeat(12,1fr);
          grid-gap: 10px;
        } 
        .item5 {
          grid-row: 3 / 6;
          grid-column: 1 / 13
          height: 250px;
        }
        
      }

      /* Carousel */
      body{padding-top:20px;}
    .carousel {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
    }
    /* The controlsy */
    .carousel-control {
      left: -12px;
        height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
        border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 23px 23px 23px 23px;
        margin-top: 90px;
    }
    .carousel-control.right {
      right: -12px;
    }
    /* The indicators */
    .carousel-indicators {
      right: 50%;
      top: auto;
      bottom: -10px;
      margin-right: -19px;
    }
    /* The colour of the indicators */
    .carousel-indicators li {
      background: #cecece;
    }
    .carousel-indicators .active {
    background: #428bca;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item5">
          <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
      
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
           
            
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              
              <div class="item active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
               
              <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
               
              <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: do you want to make only by bootstrap, or can you apply other options ..?

Comment: Hello Mohit. I am making this for a company, there is having there own CMS solution. So I do not have access to use any frameworks beside Bootstrap.

Comment: you not need to use any frameworks, you just add slider js.. like  [slick_slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)  by using this,  you can do this... which you want, .easily :)

Comment: That was looking to be a good way. I can see that I need to add the `<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>`. I do not have access to the head tag unfortunately.

Comment: yes you need to add `slick.js` and `slick.css` both... and are you also don't have access footer area? to include this?

Comment: Nope no access for that either. So the best way would be Bootstrap, but apparently there is no function for this in Bootstrap?

Comment: i think there is no option to make in one row in responsive.....

Comment: I can see this example does axcact what I need: bootsnipp.com/snippets/lVrPG. But that is made with Bootstrap 4, and I am forced to use Bootstrap 3 :-(

Comment: This could be a potential solution: https://codepen.io/Qvatra/pen/yOvBoM

Comment: but this is not convert into `one` row in mobile  device?

Comment: No that is gonna be 2 rows, but there must be a way to make that fit somehow?

Comment: good good.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using md-3 which below 991 px becomes 100% you can use sm or xs instead for that.Hope it helps.

```css
.wrapper {
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns:repeat(12,1fr);
        grid-gap: 10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 10px solid #fff;
      } 

      .wrapper > div {
        background-color: #eee;
        padding: 1em;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #ddd;
      }
      
      .item5 {
          grid-row: 3 / 6;
          grid-column: 1 / 13;
          height: 290px;
        }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .wrapper {
          display:grid;
          grid-template-columns:repeat(12,1fr);
          grid-gap: 10px;
        } 
        .item5 {
          grid-row: 3 / 6;
          grid-column: 1 / 13
          height: 250px;
        }
        
      }

      /* Carousel */
      body{padding-top:20px;}
    .carousel {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
    }
    /* The controlsy */
    .carousel-control {
      left: -12px;
        height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
        border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 23px 23px 23px 23px;
        margin-top: 90px;
    }
    .carousel-control.right {
      right: -12px;
    }
    /* The indicators */
    .carousel-indicators {
      right: 50%;
      top: auto;
      bottom: -10px;
      margin-right: -19px;
    }
    /* The colour of the indicators */
    .carousel-indicators li {
      background: #cecece;
    }
    .carousel-indicators .active {
    background: #428bca;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item5">
          <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
      
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
           
            
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              
              <div class="item active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
               
              <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
               
              <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. But this solution will make the columns extremly small. 1 thumbnail should take 12 columns. With the solution 1 thumbnail will take 3 columns.

Comment: if you make it 12 columns it will break the divs in new row which makes the height because in 1 slide you having 4 images and each will take thier height accordingly when goes to 100%.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. If you take a look at the picture in my post, and compare it with your suggestion. Then you will see that this is not the solution. On the image in my question there is 1 image. On your suggestion there is 4 images < 991px;

Comment: I can see this example does axcact what I need: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/lVrPG. But that is made with Bootstrap 4, and I am forced to use Bootstrap 3 :-(

Comment: ok got you now In bootstrap there is no option to make like this means according to screen how many slider you want to show.

Comment: Shoot okay. So that first came in Bootstrap 4 apparently. Hm that is really not good. But thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: This could be a potential solution: https://codepen.io/Qvatra/pen/yOvBoM